# How do I compute the correlation between two features and their output class?

Tags: correlation, feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction

I just read these two quotes in a paper and wondered how I do this.

> For each classifier, one selects a subset of the input features
>   according to their correlation to the corresponding class.

and

> Compute the correlation between each feature and Yi the output for class i.

Source: [Dimensionality Reduction Through Classifier Ensembles](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20000102382.pdf)

Can you tell me how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 6):

Correlation is used as a method for feature selection and is usually calculated between a feature and the output class (filter methods for feature selection). It roughly translates to how much will the change be reflected on the output class for a small change in the current feature. If the change is proportional and very high, then we say that the feature is highly correlated with the output class and is usually a very good idea to keep it around for any end of the pipeline tasks.

That being said, a feature having higher correlation in say corpus XYZ won't necessarily mean that it will have a high correlation in some other corpus say ABC and thus cannot be translated from one dataset to another.

There are many metrics to measure the correlation between a feature and a class label such as mutual information, chi-square, correlation coefficient scores etc.

[numpy.correlate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html) in python does the trick for most of my work.
or if i want to use mutual information then [sklearn has mutual info score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mutual_info_score.html) .

Answer (score 1):

This is called correlation filter. If you are using R, You can have a look at [FSelector package's](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FSelector/FSelector.pdf) `linear.correlation` and `rank.correlation` functions. When class labels are categorical, you can use Point-Biserial Correlation, polyserial or polychloric correlation.

The idea is if feature 1 is highly correlated with class label while feature 2 is not highly correlated we would select feature 1 over feature 2.